# Separating functionality into classes, communicating with the world object (cocos2d/box2d)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have my world working in my scene with Box2d. Basically a couple balls bounce around and everything is dandy.

However, I would like to add the ability to drag and drop the balls. I already can achieve this with static sprites in Cocos2D. Now with Box2D, rather than keep the code in the Layer file, I would like to move it to a CCSprite subclass (all the touch gestures, etc.)

This means I have to communicate position between the CCSprite subclass and the Layer world I guess? How does one go about doing this? Thanks

TLDR: how do you separate object logic from the Layer file to outside files?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great number of ways to do what you whant. I did it like this: In my game I have gameController - subclass of NSObject. in it's `init` method, i'm creating more controllers: 1st - for displaying Box2d objects, 2nd - for displaying come controls. If any of my objects need to tell another object about any event (collision between 2 specific b2Bodies, for example), it tells it's owner controller about that (via pointer), wich rises this event on it's parent controller, wich rises it on his parent and all his child-controllers, and so on. For example: I'm tapping on a node. All logic for tapping, dragging, etc is in it's controller class. Then, controller, that controls this node, rises event, and all other controllers knows about that, so thay can do anuthig with what, or do nothing. In this case, my box2dController gets this message and creates/moves b2Bodies.